# Random ~~~~~3~~3~~~3~~~33~~~`~~~~in SSH Console/terminal

Tags: linux, ssh

Lately when I am using SSH on the computer ( PuTTy) or on the smartphone ( Juiche SSH) I get random input with 3's and ~'s 
I don't know how to fix it, it's impossible for me to input a command the right way.

Anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: maybe you have a bad keyboard

Comment: But if the OP is getting the same symptoms on different client devices,  a faulty keyboard is an unlikely suspect.

Comment: Hello user359564. Can you please try ssh to the computer. Then, while that session is open and displaying these spurious characters, start _another_ ssh session to the same target computer. (Don't close the first one; just ignore it.) Does this second session behave properly?